# Why MSVC compiler/optimizer won't remove a duplicated function call inside a shared library, and instead duplicate the whole function body?

Tags: c++, optimization, abi

I would like to know if it's a design of the language (or maybe the shared library mechanism) or is it just a weakness of the compiler, but I'm wondering why in the first case the code gets optimized (the useless call is removed) but not in the second case.

I have a host program (test_host) which imports a shared library (test_dll).

**test_dll.h** :

```cpp
#ifdef TESTDLL_EXPORTS
#define TESTDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TESTDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class TESTDLL_API TestClass {
public:
    TestClass(void);
    int foo(int a, int b, int c);
};

#ifndef NOT_USE_BAR_FROM_DLL
TESTDLL_API int bar(TestClass* fooClass, int a, int b, int c);
#endif

#endif
```

**test_dll.cpp** :

```cpp
int TestClass::foo(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return std::printf("%d + %d - %d = %d\n", a, b, c, (a + b - c));
}

TESTDLL_API int bar(TestClass* fooClass, int a, int b, int c)
{
    return fooClass->foo(a, b, c);
}
```

**test_host.cpp**:

```cpp
#ifdef NOT_USE_BAR_FROM_DLL
int bar(TestClass* fooClass, int a, int b, int c)
{
    return fooClass->foo(a, b, c);
}
#endif

int main()
{
    TestClass inst;
    inst.foo(8, 6, 4);
    bar(&inst, 4, 7, 5);
}
```

The focus is on the **bar** function, which does absolutely nothing else than calling the foo method from the TestClass instance with the given arguments. As a method takes the hidden *this* parameter, calling bar is exactly like calling the foo method.

1. When I `#define NOT_USE_BAR_FROM_DLL` (before including test_dll.h), the compiler uses the local (from test_host) bar definition and sees that it's equivalent of calling the foo method directly, and thereby remove the call to the function to directly call the foo method instead ; we can see that within the disassembly :

```
int main()
{
00F91000  push        ebp  
00F91001  mov         ebp,esp  
00F91003  push        ecx  
    TestClass inst;
00F91004  lea         ecx,[inst]  
00F91007  call        dword ptr [__imp_TestClass::TestClass (0F920BCh)]  
    inst.foo(8, 6, 4);
00F9100D  push        4  
00F9100F  push        6  
00F91011  push        8  
00F91013  lea         ecx,[inst]  
00F91016  call        dword ptr [__imp_TestClass::foo (0F920C0h)]  
    bar(&inst, 4, 7, 5);
00F9101C  push        5  
00F9101E  push        7  
00F91020  push        4  
00F91022  lea         ecx,[inst]  
00F91025  call        dword ptr [__imp_TestClass::foo (0F920C0h)]  
}
```

2. But if I don't define the macro, the bar definition of the shared library is used, and in this case, the useless call is not optimized away as we see in the disassembly :

```
int main()
{
01091002  in          al,dx  
01091003  push        ecx  
    TestClass inst;
01091004  lea         ecx,[inst]  
01091007  call        dword ptr [__imp_TestClass::TestClass (010920BCh)]  
    inst.foo(8, 6, 4);
0109100D  push        4  
0109100F  push        6  
01091011  push        8  
01091013  lea         ecx,[inst]  
01091016  call        dword ptr [__imp_TestClass::foo (010920C0h)]  
    bar(&inst, 4, 7, 5);
0109101C  push        5  
0109101E  push        7  
01091020  lea         eax,[inst]  
01091023  push        4  
01091025  push        eax  
01091026  call        dword ptr [__imp_bar (010920C4h)]  
0109102C  add         esp,10h  
}
```

We see there that the bar function is called, and its address is different from the foo method, so bar has its own code. Does anyone know why it won't optimize the call when the function resides in the shared library ? I mean, the compiler could atleast set the import address of the bar function as the one of TestClass::foo, because calling TestClass::foo is exactly the same as calling bar.

It's even worse, because if I look into the content of the bar disassembled code (in the shared library), it does not call the foo method but instead contains a copy of the foo method's body. At the beginning I would like to remove an additional call, but if the whole code body is duplicated instead, it's worse.

I made this test because I was looking for clean ways to make a C++ library (using an OOP API) but also add a C API in it which translate function calls to class methods, in a portable way (such that the library could be used in both a C and C++ OOP way. But it's a bit sad if the compiler is not able to do these basic optimizations.

Of course a function call is negligible, but I would like to know if someone has an idea about that, if the behaviour of the compiler is just tighted to the ABI requirements, or if I could use compiler options to force an optimization which would stay clean and portable, ABI-correct (anyway I don't know if this behaviour is MSVC-specific or if gcc, llvm and others do the same).

*Disassembly of foo and bar in the DLL* :

```
int TestClass::foo(int a, int b, int c)
{
51051070  push        ebp  
51051071  mov         ebp,esp  
    return std::printf("%d + %d - %d = %d\n", a, b, c, (a + b - c));
51051073  mov         edx,dword ptr [c]  
51051076  mov         ecx,dword ptr [a]  
51051079  mov         eax,dword ptr [b]  
5105107C  sub         ecx,edx  
5105107E  add         ecx,eax  
51051080  push        ecx  
51051081  push        edx  
51051082  push        eax  
51051083  push        dword ptr [a]  
51051086  push        offset string "%d + %d - %d = %d\n" (510520A4h)  
5105108B  call        printf (51051030h)  
51051090  add         esp,14h  
}

TESTDLL_API int bar(TestClass* fooClass, int a, int b, int c)
{
510510A0  push        ebp  
510510A1  mov         ebp,esp  
    return fooClass->foo(a, b, c);
510510A3  mov         edx,dword ptr [c]  
510510A6  mov         ecx,dword ptr [a]  
510510A9  mov         eax,dword ptr [b]  
510510AC  sub         ecx,edx  
510510AE  add         ecx,eax  
510510B0  push        ecx  
510510B1  push        edx  
510510B2  push        eax  
510510B3  push        dword ptr [a]  
510510B6  push        offset string "%d + %d - %d = %d\n" (510520A4h)  
510510BB  call        printf (51051030h)  
510510C0  add         esp,14h  
}
```

In other words, I would like the bar function in the library to behave like in test_host, that is being a "symlink" to the foo method; either by having the same exported address, in this case the export table of test_dll would be like that :

```
0x000920C0 foo@TestClass
0x000920C0 bar
```

Or either by telling the compiler during compilation of test_host to know that the imported "bar" could be ignored and TestClas::foo be used instead (but I guess it would not work from a C host because the TestClass could not be declared, the compiler would not be able to know that bar can be understood as TestClass::foo).

This way a usage of my library within both a C and C++ host would have the same cost of function/method calls.

Is it possible ?

Comment: You have ignored `__declspec(dllexport)` `__declspec(dllimport)` which means this function will be exported/imported from dll. Without it linker will not be aware that dll can contain this symbol, so linker will not report a conflict and will just use symbol which is know to him.

Comment: Well the declspec thing is intended. I want the bar function from inside the library to behave like the one I use in my test_host : being exported, but not as an independent function, just as a "symlink" to TestClass::foo, in the way where calling bar of the library is exactly the same as calling TestClass::foo

Comment: The compiler has no idea what `bar` from the dll is doing, how do you want it to be able to optimise it away?

Comment: If you want two function to be merged in the dll, why are you talking about your main program? It is irrelevant to how dll is built.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have the two functions merged because they use different calling conventions. The non-static member function uses [__thiscall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/thiscall?view=msvc-160) while the standalone function uses [__cdecl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=msvc-160).

You should note that in your case the compiled code of `bar` does not include an actual call to `foo`, but have `foo` inlined, so there is no execution time penalty.

Comment: Would it be possible to force the C function (bar) to use the same calling convention as the foo method to achieve that ?

Comment: Don't bother with micro-optimisations.